# What's the best way to make usage of Django behind a lighttpd reverse proxy?

Tags: django, lighttpd, django-deployment

This is more a question for some general thing.

I've got a lighttpd running and want to connect it as a reverse proxy with Django 1.6. I've read a lot about wsgi, gunicorn ... well, not sure what's the current best way of doing this?

Comment: There is no best way. There are just ways: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/ Personally I would go for gunicorn.

Comment: Can you give a short hint about the reasons are just "because it works"?

Comment: Well, it's more like "because I've worked with it and it works". Plus it is very easy to setup.